# .NET FromBase64String length

Tags: c#, .net

If I run  Convert.FromBase64String("test") I get the error that it's invalid length. I'm trying to convert to a byte array so I can encrypt it, but on shorter strings it's giving the length error. I tried rpadding with '=' but no matter how many I put nothing seems to work.

What are my options with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have text data that you need to store as binary:

- You convert a string to byte[] via Encoding.GetBytes(), for example Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()
- you convert such text data back to a string via Encoding.GetString(); this requires the binary to be valid text data via this encoding (not arbitrary binary)

If you have binary data you need to store as a string;

- you convert *arbitrary* binary to a string with Convert.ToBase64String()
- you convert such a string back to binary with Convert.FromBase64String(); this requires the string to be a valid base-64 string (not an arbitrary string)

So: look at Encoding.

Comment: It looks like this includes comma's and quotes. I take multiple pieces of text and concat them together and make a csv string. I then send that over to the server where I split on comma then decrypt. This seems like it work work then.

Comment: OK I got it. I use the Encoding to convert to bytes so it can be encrypted then I take the bytes from encryption and use ToBase64String() and I send that over to the server as a csv string and just reverse it on the other end.

Thanks

Comment: @user441521: If your data is just "text" (i.e., does not include any characters that are reserved by whatever protocol you are using to send the data) or if you are sending the data using a library that knows how to handle encoding already, then there is no need to encode and decode your strings.  Your question doesn't really make it clear what you are trying to accomplish.  As for using encryption, if you are encrypting the text you will usually want to apply encoding *after* encryption and decoding before decryption.

Answer (score 6):

Base64 is a method of converting a byte sequence into a specially-formatted string.
`"test"` isn't a Base64 string.

You're looking for `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test")`

Comment: And one of the reasons it's not a Base64 string is because the expected length is incorrect :)